# How do i change the color of a specific part of a link on hover?

Tags: css

Its hard to explain so i have an example

I have a left part that should remain black and a right part that is green which changes to red on hover see http://jsfiddle.net/z9jSS/

I want this to LOOK THE SAME but i want make the left part a link too and have the right part change color when i hover over it like the first link. I know how to disable the underline but what i dont know how to do is not have the left part change red on hover while having the right part change colors
http://jsfiddle.net/z9jSS/2/

Is there some trick i can do so a:hover will make a color change red but force the left part to stay black?

Comment: You had the solution, you just forgot the '.' in front of your class names 'l' and 'r'

Comment: @Alain >_< I was so close. But even after fixing the html and adding the '.' it is still horribly broken http://jsfiddle.net/z9jSS/28/

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Posted a more complete solution below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply override the styles for your spans:

```
.c a { text-decoration: none; color: inherit; }
.c a:hover .r { color:red; text-decoration: underline; }
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/z9jSS/21/

Comment: ah ha, i didnt realize you can put more after a `:whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like everything above was missing one thing or another. This includes everything you asked for, with part of the link being plain black text, and the rest being a green underlined link that turns red when hovering.

http://jsfiddle.net/z9jSS/30/

```
.c a          { color: black; text-decoration: none; }
.c a .r       { color: green; text-decoration: underline; }
.c a:hover .r { color: red;   text-decoration: underline; }
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `text-decoration: underline` on `.c a:hover .r`.

Answer (score 1):

wrap the part of anchor inside a span or an other tag

try [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9jSS/6/)

Comment: Plain black part is changing colour too though :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.c a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none
}
.c a span:first-child + span {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: green;
}
.c a:hover span:first-child + span {
    color: red
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/z9jSS/31/

This has the benefit of not needing either of the `.l` or `.r` classes.

It will work in all browsers except IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Override the styles with a higher specificy style.

```
.c a:hover span.l { color: blue; }
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/z9jSS/19/)**.